# How to change default timezone UTC to Local timezone

Tags: wordpress, timezone

I'm maintaining a WordPress based website which I observed not working following local time. It follows default UTC timezone. I tried from General Setting but yet the site is working based on default UTC timezone. How can I fix it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are couple of solutions I can suggest.

1. Check if the settings are being saved. Sometimes settings are not being saved. It happened for me with Wordpress blog hosted on Windows Azure.
2. If you are using custom theme. Make sure it does not override the time

   ```
   get_post_time('U', true);
   ```

The second parameter is true, which forces WordPress to use GMT timezone rather than using your local timezone.

You can go through the functions in order to check it..

Similar situation here : http://wordpress.org/support/topic/how-to-display-local-time-instead-of-utc

If you can share the theme files or the file where date function is written, I can help you with it :-)

Comment: Thanks a lot, Rahul. Let me clear you more specifically by my bad English skill. There is a section named "Today's Post" where only today's post are displayed. I found that the section is following that UTC timezone not the Local time. Probably the reason is hardcoded UTC timezone which I want to change. Probably "i18n" (http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/date_i18n) is a one of the solutions but I am unable to get how should apply.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the JetPack plugin installed, deactivate it then reactivate again - make sure you're already in the proper timezone setting before doing this though.

I've experienced this when I had JetPack installed while not having the proper timezone setting (and tried some PHP time functions). JetPack for some reason saves the original setting and forces it on WP.

Comment: Thanks Adrian for the comment. JetPack is not installed in the site.